# Is Polymerized lithium niobocene a possible compound?

Tags: organometallic-compounds, chemistry-in-fiction

I was doing some research on different types of body armor and found a fictional compound by the name of Polymerized LiNb. I wanted to find what the structure of this compound looked like so it could be recreated. But to my surprise, nothing is on the internet about it. So I was hoping that someone up here could tell me how it could be formed and polymerized and if it could be used in the piezoelectric effect.

Comment: Nothing is on the internet about it? You should brush up your google-fu ;)

Comment: If it was real, our world probably wouldn't be what it is. Don't you think?

Comment: The Li-Nb phase diagram is quite simple - there are no known compounds in the system. Solubility measurements indicate that the heat of mixing is on the order of 100-300 kJ/mol which is quite large (particularly considering that both Nb and the high temperature phase of Li are both bcc). The two want nothing to do with each other...

Comment: Niobocene is a sandwich compound of Nb. I imagine one could call plenty of organometallic polymers in similar fashion, but the name itself is vague and incorrect.